# How would I hypothetically display the number of iterations in this forloop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

In my hypothetical R code below, I am using two packages called "DBA" and "EBA" to generate data sets with missing data for the following sample sizes: 50, 150, 250, 350. This will give a total of 8 iterations (4 for DBA and 4 for EBA). The desired missing percentage is 20% and the other desired parameters are listed.

When I run the code, it works, and it says "% of missing values: XX %" 8 times to show that each of the 8 iterations generated ~20% missing. However, after that, I want it to display the number of iterations that ran (8 in this case). So for it to say something like "Number of iterations: 8". That way when I get to hundreds of iterations, I know it worked and didn't miss any iterations. How do I do this? Hypothetical R code is below. Thanks!

#Start of loop

```
for (mechanism in c("DBA", "EBA")){

  for (sample.size in c(50, 150, 250, 350)) {

  d1 <-  ml_data(

    n_pers=sample.size,
    n_time= 5,
    beta_int=0,
    beta_time=0.3,
    beta_covar=0.5,
    mean_r=0,
    var_r=1)
# trim the number of variables
    mydata <- d1[,c(1,2,3,8)]

#Generate missing data 
    mydata <- produce_NA(mydata, mechanism, perc.missing = 0.2)
    X.mydata <- mydata$data.incomp
  #Output the percetage of newly generated missing values
    R.mydata <- mydata$idx_newNA
    writeLines(paste0("Percentage of newly generated missing values: ", 
                      100*sum(R.mydata)/prod(dim(R.mydata)), " %"))

    }

 }
```

Comment: Create a variable e.g. `loopCount <- 0` before the loop.  After your `writelines` add `loopCount <- loopCount + 1`.  After the loop add `print(paste0("total loop count: ",loopcount))`

Comment: Another option would be to put the output of your loop into a data frame (for later saving/printing/manipulation) in which case just checking the number of rows in the data frame would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

one option with base R, avoiding loops:

```
my_grid <- 
  expand.grid(
    mechanism = c("DBA", "EBA"),
    sample.size = c(50, 150, 250, 350)
  ) |>
  ## cbind incoming grid with its rownumbers:
  (\(.x) cbind(.x, iteration = 1:nrow(.x)))()
```

```
## > my_grid
##   mechanism sample.size iteration
## 1       DBA          50         1
## 2       EBA          50         2
## 3       DBA         150         3
## 4       EBA         150         4
## 5       DBA         250         5
## 6       EBA         250         6
## 7       DBA         350         7
## 8       EBA         350         8
```

row-wise process above grid with a custom function:

```
my_row_function = \(the_row){
  ## do stuff ...
  writeLines(paste('iteration: ', the_row['iteration'],
                   'mechanism: ', the_row['mechanism']
                   )
             )
}
```

```
my_grid |> apply(MARGIN = 1, FUN =  my_row_function)
```

```
## > my_grid |> apply(MARGIN = 1, FUN =  my_row_function)
## iteration:  1 mechanism:  DBA
## iteration:  2 mechanism:  EBA
## iteration:  3 mechanism:  DBA
## truncated
```

Beyond base R, I'd recommend to look into `iwalk`, `imap` from {purrr} or rowwise `mutate`ion of {dplyr}